# Adding stuff from repository to context EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm kinda confused here.

I've created a Web API with a controller to get a list of pokemons (public pokemon API) and add them into a SQL database.

I'm using the repository pattern and got kinda lost. How do I pass the deserialized object from my repository to my controller and add it to the `DataContext` (so it would get added to the database)?

In my repository class, I do an http request, get the objects, deserialize them, so far so good. However I'm having messages about incompatible types when running things on swagger (for testing).

I've seen another question here on SO with a similar problem, but I haven't managed to successfully apply the solution there to my project.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

I'll post the classes that belong to my project:

PokemonDtoesController.cs

```
namespace MyPokeAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PokemonDtoesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IPokemonRepository repository;

        public PokemonDtoesController(DataContext context, IPokemonRepository _repository)
        {
            this.repository = _repository;
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/PokemonDtoes
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PokemonDto>>> GetPokemonDto()
        {
            var items = (await repository.GetAllPokemonsAsync());
            _context.Add(items);

            return _context;
        }

        // GET: api/PokemonDtoes/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PokemonDto>> GetPokemonDto(int id)
        {
            var pokemonDto = await _context._pokemons.FindAsync(id);

            if (pokemonDto == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return pokemonDto;
        }

        private bool PokemonDtoExists(int id)
        {
            return _context._pokemons.Any(e => e.id == id);
        }
    }
```

`PokemonRepository`:

```
namespace MyPokeAPI.Repositories
{
    public class PokemonRepository : IPokemonRepository
    {
        private HttpClient _client;
        private PokemonDto currPoke = null;
        private string json = string.Empty;
        int limit = 30;

        private readonly List<PokemonDto> pokemons = new List<PokemonDto>();     

        public async Task<IEnumerable<PokemonDto>> GetAllPokemonsAsync()
        {
            string url = $"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset={limit}&limit={limit}";

            using (_client = new HttpClient())
            {
                _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    BaseResults myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseResults>(json);

                    if (myDeserializedClass != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var result in myDeserializedClass.results)
                        {
                            using (HttpClient insideclient = new HttpClient())
                            {
                                insideclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(result.url);
                                response = await insideclient.GetAsync(result.url);

                                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                    //AbilitiesRoot currPokeAbilities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbilitiesRoot>(json);
                                    currPoke = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokemonDto>(json);
                                    if (currPoke != null)
                                    {
                                        pokemons.Add(currPoke);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return pokemons;
        }

        public PokemonDto GetSinglePokemonAsync(string name)
        {
            return pokemons.Where(item => item.name == name).SingleOrDefault();
        }
     }
```

DataContext.cs

```
namespace MyPokeAPI.Helper
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString"));
        }

        public DbSet<PokemonDto> _pokemons { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: You are explicitly intended to NOT implement your own repositories when using EF. The `DbContext` is a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

Comment: I understood. if so, how i make my http request inside the controller and return it to the context (to get written into the DB)? I can put the logic there but i don't know a way to convert\insert it into the _context.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. You wouldn't use a repository to access the EF data but if you have other data sources as well then you could/would have your own repositories for them. Your service layer would be responsible for retrieving from one data source and passing the data into the other.

Comment: I've removed the repository and transfered the logic to the controller. No problem so far, but how can i add the deserialized object to the _context ? I've reseted my migrations so they would match my current classes and created the db again, but i'm having an InnerException saying "Invalid Object: Ability"(its a class i'm using to deserialize). How can i debug what is going on, could you help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

In your Get method you are returning the db context but you are declaring an `IEnumerable<PokemonDto>`, is for that you have this error of incompatible types. You should return `items` or `_context._pokemons`. The items got from the repository you should insert them in the `_context._pokemons` that is the collection referencing your pokemons table in db, using the method `AddRange()` because you are inserting a list of objects. When you save the context, those new records will be inserted in the DB, so, is for that you should also call `_context.SaveChanges()` in order to save all modifications made to the db context.

```
// GET: api/PokemonDtoes
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PokemonDto>>> GetPokemonDto()
{
    var items = await repository.GetAllPokemonsAsync();
    _context._pokemons.AddRange(items);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(items);
}
```

After save the changes to the db context, you can get the list you saved everywere in your application.

I hope that helps you.